# Simplify Constructor for class with multiple initialisable fields

Tags: c#, constructor-overloading

I currently have the following problem:
I have a class which includes 3 different fields

- Enum x
- ActiveDirectoryUser y
- CustomClass z

The enum can be initialised by passing a string or the enum object.
The ADUser can be initialised by passing a string (LoginName) or the user by itself and the CustomClass can be initialized by passing a string, int or the object.

Now I want to initialize the class to pass all different combinations like

```
class(string enumValue, string adUser, string customClass) 
class(string enumValue, ADUser adUser, CustomClass customClass)
class(EnumValue enumValue, string adUser, CustomClass customClass)
```

Is there a way to simplify the constructors without typing all of the 12 possibilities (Enum-2 * ADUser-2 * CClass-3 = 12)?

I thought about chained constructors where i also ended up with 12 constructors but also thought about just passing the c# Object on each parameter and cast it and do stuff with it but i think that is just a dirty workaround?

## Edit

The class is contained in an library and so can be used internal but also public. For the internal uses there is no problem to pass a concrete version of an object.
But if i use it public in other solutions these solutions can only refer to string or int values. So the class should be able to 'take' the values and convert them while beeing initialised because it have access to all the real objects.
Maybe this clarifies the problem a bit.

Here some code snippets with changed names:

```
#region Content of libraryOne

public class ClassName
{
    internal EnumValueWrapper { get; set; }
    internal CustomClass { get; set; }
    internal ADUser { get; set; }

    public ClassName() { ... } //Now via Builder Pattern
    internal ClassName() { ... } //With Parameters for internal initialisations

    public InformationContainer GetContentInfo()
    {
        //[...]Process Stuff and Return Container
    }
}

internal CustomClass { ... }
internal EnumValueWrapper { ... }
internal ADUser { ... }

#endregion Content of libraryOne
```

Comment: I would advise against allowing anything other than the concrete versions of the objects initialising the constructor. So class(EnumValue enumvalue, ADUser adUser, CustomClass customClass) would be the only constructor I have. But without seeing further code and how this is architectured I don't know if this would work.

Comment: JamesThorpe ADUser, EnumValue and CustomClass are all pre initialised. The class should just pick the right one from a pool which it has access to.

DanielCasserly i will update some informations fro the architecture

Comment: Consider asking this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or by looking for a similar question on that site

Comment: You're solving this problem at the wrong level. Add implicit or explicit conversions where possible, or just make the caller pass the right type. Then you only need one constructor: `EnumValue, ADUser, CustomClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best thing to do is use the Builder pattern. You can even use it with derived classes.

My classes to build:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public MyBaseClass(SomeEnum enumValue, User user)
    {
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass(SomeEnum enumValue, User user, CustomClass customStuff)
        : base(enumValue, user)
    {
    }
}
```

Now let's add a builder class featuring an additional extension class for making things much more comfortable (it's sort of an extended Builder pattern using C# extension method wizadry):

```
public class MyBaseClassBuilder
{
    public SomeEnum EnumValue { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}

public static class MyBaseClassBuilderExtensions
{
    public static T SetEnumValue<T>(this T instance, SomeEnum value)
        where T : MyBaseClassBuilder
    {
        instance.EnumValue = value;
        return instance;
    }

    public static T SetEnumValue<T>(this T instance, string value)
        where T : MyBaseClassBuilder
    {
        instance.EnumValue = (SomeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(SomeEnum), value);
        return instance;
    }

    public static T SetUser<T>(this T instance, User value)
        where T : MyBaseClassBuilder
    {
        instance.User = value;
        return instance;
    }

    public static T SetUser<T>(this T instance, string value)
        where T : MyBaseClassBuilder
    {
        instance.User = new User(value);
        return instance;
    }

    public static MyBaseClass Build(this MyBaseClassBuilder instance)
    {
        return new MyBaseClass(instance.EnumValue, instance.User);
    }
}
```

Now let's do the same thing for our derived class:

```
public class MyDerivedClassBuilder : MyBaseClassBuilder
{
    public CustomClass CustomStuff { get; set; }
}

public static class MyDerivedClassBuilderExtensions
{
    public static T SetCustomStuff<T>(this T instance, CustomClass value)
        where T : MyDerivedClassBuilder
    {
        instance.CustomStuff = value;
        return instance;
    }

    public static T SetCustomStuff<T>(this T instance, string value)
        where T : MyDerivedClassBuilder
    {
        instance.CustomStuff = new CustomClass(value);
        return instance;
    }

    public static MyDerivedClass Build(this MyDerivedClassBuilder instance)
    {
        return new MyDerivedClass(instance.EnumValue, instance.User, instance.CustomStuff);
    }
}
```

Now you can construct your instances in some fluent API style way:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyBaseClass baseInstance = new MyBaseClassBuilder()
            .SetEnumValue("Alpha")
            .SetUser("Big Duke")
            .Build();

        MyDerivedClass derivedInstance = new MyDerivedClassBuilder()
            .SetEnumValue(SomeEnum.Bravo)
            .SetUser(new User("Lt. Col. Kilgore"))
            .SetCustomStuff("Smells like victory")
            .Build();
    }
```

Finally the additional types:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    Alpha,
    Bravo
}

public class User
{
    public User(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
}

public class CustomClass
{
    public CustomClass(string notation)
    {
        this.Notation = notation;
    }

    public string Notation { get; private set; }
}
```

This way you can construct instances which require many constructor arguments in a comfortable way.

Comment: Wow this is huge. Never heard of a 'builder pattern'. *shame on me* I Guess this will do the job even if i can't use the classes Constructor directly. If there's a way to use the construct in such a way i would be proud (just for Code cleanliness) but for now i'll mark your answer as solution. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't quite understand what is **internal** in your code. Can you give me a code extract? Or tell me which parts of my code example have to be changed or made **internal**?

Comment: Uhm, I'll try it. 
In My case the class is in a library together with CustomClass, EnumValue and User. The 3 other classes have an internal List of possible items which are each filled through a static constructor and all have a internal constructor aswell. So only the class could create new one or each class itself. The fields in class are internal aswell so nobody from outside can watch its content except through the public methods of class. With outside i mean classes not included in the library. Does that explain it a bit?

Comment: To be honest: nope. You say _List_ _of_ _possible_ _items_ _which_ _are_ _each_ _filled_ _through_ _a_ _static_ _constructor_. Do you really mean a **static constructor**? Or do you mean **static construction methods**? However: I think I can't help you if I don't see the concrete code.

Answer (score 1):

If your class has only 3 properties (`EnumValue, ADUser, CustomClass`) then you should have only one constructor with these :`class(EnumValue enumValue, ADUser adUser, CustomClass customClass)`. The `ADUser` and `CustomClass` should be instantiated outside of your class using their constructor which support `string` or `int`, etc;
Example:

```
class (EnumValue param, new ADUser(string_param), new CustomClass(int_param));
class (EnumValue param, new ADUser(ADUser_param), new CustomClass(string_param));
```

**Edit**
You can use it like I described above for internal scope and for the public part you can use and expose a factory (wrapper) class which actually can receive users and other parameters as strings or int and internally instantiate and return your class.

**In addition to your snippet:** Create a proxy like **public** class in your assembly that can be accessed from outside (from other assemblies).Make your class internal:

```
   public class ClassNameBuilder
   {
        private ClassName _className;

        public ClassNameBuilder(string enumValue, string user, string custom_class) 
        { 
           _className = new ClassName(EnumToString, new User(user), new CustomClass(custom_class));

        } 

        public void CallClassNameMethod1()
        {
            return _className.Method1()
        }

        public void CallClassNameMethod2()
        {
            return _className.Method2()
        }
}
```

The builder class can use whatever method you want to build the ClassName object; This way you can expose all your class methods without using multiple constructors.

Comment: Yea, that would solve the problem but i forgot to mention the restriction through the library. I edited my post. Thank you.